# PHP mysql error when running INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Can someone help me understand this error?

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\MAMP\htdocs\MyCMS\insert_posttwo.php on line 64

```
<?php    

    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "mycms");

    if (isset($_POST['submit'] )) {  
        $post_author    = $_POST['post_author'];

       $stmt = $mysqli->prepare ("INSERT INTO 'posts' ('post_author') VALUES(?)");

       $stmt->bind_param('s', $post_auth);

       $post_auth =     $post_author;
       $stmt->execute();


       echo "<script>alert('Post has been published')</script>";
       echo "<script>window.open('insert_post','_self')</script>";

       $stmt->close();

   }

?>
```

Comment: backticks `\`` instead of single quotes `'` are used on table/column names -> `"INSERT INTO \`posts\` (\`post_author\`) 
   VALUES(?)"`

Comment: Use started the connection with the procedural method. Use the object method $mysqli = new mysql(...

Comment: Also u have not declared $stmt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of single quotes `'` use backticks `` ` `` to escape field or table names .

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare ("INSERT INTO `posts` (`post_author`) VALUES(?)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this (For columns you have to use back ticks not single quotes):

```
'posts'
```

to:

```
`posts`
```

Also you have to create a object and not the procedural method otherwise you can't do that so use this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "mycms");
        //^^^ See here so you create a object
```

And also you have to close your connection like this:

```
$mysqli->close();
//^^^^^ Close the connection and not the stmt
```

Comment: Thanks guys!! that work brilliantly. But isn't it terrible practice to keep the username and password in a php file?  Is it possible to inspect the file and find the username and password?

Comment: @rrrrrr You're welcome! What do you mean with: `keep the username and password in a php file`?

Comment: just to clarify, for example -- the connection string has my username and password exposed in text format (in this case it's root root).. but in a real project this will contain the username and password